# Need help updating text, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a game in javascript for school but I ran into a problem with updating the counters. Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```js
function drawUnits() {
  ctx.drawImage(log, 380, 5, 32, 32);
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText(logy, 420, 21);
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.fillText("Logs", 420, 21);
}

function Dayend(message) {
  if (message == 1) {
    ctx.width = ctx.width;
    alert("You chopped some trees");
    var logy = logy + 4;
    DrawUnits()
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 85) {
    Dayend(1);
  }
});
```

With logy being a variable which is defined earlier and log being a picture als defined earlier.

I don't get what is wrong with the code but as soon as I press the button I do get the alert but the counter doesn't update

Thank you all, I used both your answers and changed some unrelated stuff and it magically worked again :)

Comment: Your code is incomplete and poorly formatted, and your title hardly reflects anything. Please browse the [help].

Comment: ofcourse it is incomplete do you want me to fit 500 lines of code in here? And it may be poorly formatted but that is because I am farely new here. I don't really get what you meant with the titel part though.

Comment: Hopefully that edit clears it up for anyone who might help but it looks like the issue is possibly related to `var logy = logy + 4;`. I don't think you mean to declare and then immediately assign the now undefined variable to itself as this results in `logy` being `NaN`. You also have issues with consistency in your function names (e.g. `drawUnits` and `DrawUnits`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing several close brackets, so it is not runnable. Please fix it. Also, in you comment you mention that logy is defined somewhere before the above code, but you are redefining a local variable with the sam ename in the Dayend() function. Could that be your issue, that the local logy variable is getting set instead of your global one? Try chaiging:

```
var logy = logy + 4;
```

to

```
logy += 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-instantiating the variable `logy` with `var`. Try replacing the last few lines with this:

```
function Dayend(message) {
    if(message == 1){
        ctx.width = ctx.width;
        alert("You chopped some trees");
        logy = logy + 4;
        DrawUnits()
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure that `logy` is tracked on the global state, and that you aren't overwriting it somewhere else. You might be better off passing the value to `DrawUnits()`.